# Using a single factory/repository to create/lookup multiple types

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

Is it considered bad practice to have a single factory/repository capable of creating/looking-up several different types of objects (all of which inherit from a abstract base class)? I haven’t been able to find anyone who says anything about it one way or the other, but all the Factory examples I've seen appear to have 1 type of factory for every type of item that needs to be created.

In my case, I have over 150 classes that inherit from `ModelBase` that need to be created dynamically from my ViewModels. Each buisness class has several services that need to be Dependency Injected into their constructors, but I do not want my ViewModels to have access to these services. The only (elegant) solution I can think of for this is to create a BizFactory/Repository for creating/looking-up anything that inherits from `ModelBase`. All ModelBase classes have to implement a `Save()` and `Delete()`, so it's not necessary from the BizFactory to handle saving...

```
public interface IBizFactory
{
     public T GetById<T>(int id) where T:ModelBase;
     public IList<T> GetAll<T>()  where T:ModelBase;
     public T Create<T>()  where T:ModelBase;
}

public class BizFactory: IBizFactory
{
     private IDataStoreFactory datafactory;

     public BizFactory(IDataStoreFactory datafactory)
     {
        this.datafactory = datafactory; 
     }

     ...
}
```

On further reflection...

The only time I've seen something that remotely looks like this is DbContext... in this case you use the same type of object (your DbContext), perhaps even the same instance, to lookup any of your entities using the `Set<T>()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed [shape of `IBizFactory` suggests that it's a Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryorServiceLocator), which [is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern), although that somewhat [depends on the role in which it's being used](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics).

Instead, consider an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IBizFactory<T> where T : ModelBase
{
     public T GetById(int id);
     public IList<T> GetAll();
     public T Create();
}
```

That is, if you need an interface for this at all.

Since you have over 150 classes that derive from `ModelBase`, this would also indicate over 150 constructed instances of `IBizFactory<T>` (one for each `T`), so it would most likely be easiest to [implement it](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory) using a convention-based approach to a DI Container; basically, let the DI Container scan your assemblies to find all relevant `ModelBase` classes. IIRC, [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor) can easily do something like that.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that in order to prevent my ViewModel from having access to the services that my ModelBase child classes (and therefore my ModelBaseFactory) are dependent on, I would have to dependency inject  a different `ModelBaseFactory<T>` for each type of ModelBase  that my ViewModel needs?  

For example, If my ViewModel needs to create both `Individual`s and `Badge`s, my ViewModel would have a constructor that would look like `MyViewModel(ModelBaseFactory<Individual> indFactory, ModelBaseFactory<Badge> badgeFactory, ….) `

Comment: Also, would it be ok to have 1 implementation of `IBizFactory<T>` that uses reflection to create/lookup instances of `T`. I would rather like to avoid having to define 150+ classes that derive from `IBizFactory<Individual>`, `IBizFactory<Badge>`, etc.

Comment: Aren't ViewModels passive data structures without behaviour?

Comment: View models are an abstract represention of the state of your view. They are also intended to store most (if not all) of your application logic (as opposed to buisness logic). In fact, most logic you usually find in a code behind of a WinForm or WebForms app would be in the ViewModel of a wpf/mvvm app. In my case, this logic requires me to create new instances of my Model objects.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing MVVM with WPF. In that case, chapter 7 in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG) has more details about wiring up all dependencies in such an application. You can also refer to the article on [implementing Abstract Factories](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory) for more details.